# How can i display GIF images in map tip using ArcGIS silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-silverlight-api

I'd like to display GIF image in map tip using Silverlight API .I found the below code but it doesn't work for GIF image. Is there any way to display GIF images in map tip using ArcGIS silverlight API?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="/Assets/images/i_zoomin.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIF Images are not supported by Microsoft Silverlight, which ArcGIS Explorer Online is built with. I'd suggest using a different image format like png.
Check this link: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/36424-images-in-pop-ups-are-not-shown-in-all-apis